# A way to animate video brightness

Tags: video

I’ve placed a video of lava onto part of a mesh and wanted it to start out dim and brighten over time. Is there a way to keyframe this in Blender?

Thanks,
Rusty

Answer (score 1):

you can animated the value of Exposure if you want to brighten all the scene

[image]

Comment: Note that by changing the exposure you are affecting the brightness of the whole scene. It might make more sense to change the emission value in the shader, so that the brightness of the texture interacts more realistically with other objects in the scene.

Comment: @no-can-do yes, I don't know why but I remember that the original question was different..